# Template Path issue in Presenter (ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2, presenter

I moved my render_listable helper into a presenter and now my render path is wrong, as the render method can not see the template.

#### How do I fix the path to the template path?

### Error

> ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial search/_listing_car with
>   {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf,
>   :vtt, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :svg, :mpeg, :mp3, :ogg, :m4a,
>   :webm, :mp4, :otf, :ttf, :woff, :woff2, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml,
>   :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :gzip],
>   :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby,
>   :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: ):

```
>     3:     <div class="col-md-12 vertical-right">
>     4:            <% if listings && listings.size > 0 %>
>     5:                <% listings.each do |listing_object| %>
>     6:           <%= listing_object.render_listable %>
>     7:                    <hr/>
>     8:                <% end %>
>     9:
>
```

> app/presenters/listing_presenter.rb:60:in `render_listable'
>   app/views/search/_searchresults.html.erb:6:in`block in
>   _app_views_search__searchresults_html_erb___9192204423298974_70140171600340'
>   app/views/search/_searchresults.html.erb:5:in `each'
>   app/views/search/_searchresults.html.erb:5:in`
>   _app_views_search__searchresults_html_erb___919234423298974_70140171600340'
>   app/views/search/index.js.erb:3:in
>   `_app_views_search_index_js_erb___2514407173266410_70140171518260'

My templates are in..

MyAppName/app/views/search/_listing_car.html.erb
MyAppName/app/views/search/_listing_truck.html.erb

### Presenter

```
class ListingPresenter < ApplicationPresenter

  def render_listable
    case listable_type
    when "Car"
      h.render partial: "search/listing_car", locals: { listing: self }
    when "Truck"
      h.render partial: "search/listing_truck", locals: { listing: self }
    else
      "NO TEMPLATE RENDERED"
    end
  end
end
```

### Application Presenter

```
class ApplicationPresenter
  delegate_missing_to :@object


  def initialize(object)
    @object = object
  end

  def h
    ActionController::Base.helpers
  end

  def routes
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  end 

  def self.present(obj, presenter_class = nil)
    klass = presenter_class || presenter_name(obj).constantize
    klass.new obj 
  end

  def self.wrap_collection(collection)
    collection.map { |obj| self.present(obj) }
  end

  private

  def self.presenter_name(model)
    if model.class == Listing
      "#{model.listable_type}Presenter"
    else
      "#{model.class}Presenter"
    end
  end
end
```

#### Note:

I noticed that if I pass a viewcontext in, rather than use my ActionController::Base.helpers method (the h method), it works.

### However, I would prefer to not have to pass the view_context in.

```
  def render_listable(view_context)
    case listable_type
    when "Car"
      view_context.render partial: "search/listing_car", locals: { listing: self }
    when "Truck"
      view_context.render partial: "search/listing_truck", locals: { listing: self }
    else
      "NO TEMPLATE RENDERED"
    end
  end
```

So when I call from the view..

`listing.listable_type(self)`,

but I want

`listing.listable_type`

Comment: What is the correct path? In your error, what comes after `Searched in:`?

Comment: @jvillian updated. thanks

Comment: Those weird methods like "h" or "routes" are a sign of a bad design idea. Maybe you just need a helper method and not a presenter class.

Comment: Need better organization around my helpers, so I am transferring them to presenters.  Why are they bad design?